# Multiple image resizing in PHP

Tags: php, image, upload

I am trying to resize the image. It works fine with single image. But with multiple image, I have to use loop to get images one by one. So I am keeping the class and its functions in different file in order to not to get error of class re-declaration. So I have 3 files One is index.php, One is class.php and other is functions.php, they all are below.

I am getting the error of **Call to undefined method resize::resizeImage()**

Below is my code for index

```
<?php


// *** Include the class

$tmp = "image1.jpg,image2.jpg";

$single=explode(',',$tmp);
foreach($single as $single){

// include_once("class.php");
include_once("class.php");

// *** 1) Initialise / load image
$resizeObj = new resize('./images/'.$single.'');

// *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(420, 290, 'auto');

// *** 3) Save image
$resizeObj -> saveImage('1-'.$single.'', 100);

}
```

?>

And below is my class file

```
Class resize
    {

        private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
        private $imageResized;
             }
```

And here's the functions file

```
<?php


        function __construct($fileName)
        {
            // *** Open up the file
            $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

            // *** Get width and height
            $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
            $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function openImage($file)
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                    break;
                case '.gif':
                    $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                    break;
                case '.png':
                    $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    break;
                default:
                    $img = false;
                    break;
            }
            return $img;
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
        {
            // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
            $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

            $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


            // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


            // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
            if ($option == 'crop') {
                $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
        {

           switch ($option)
            {
                case 'exact':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'portrait':
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    break;
                case 'landscape':
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    break;
                case 'auto':
                    $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
                case 'crop':
                    $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                    break;
            }
            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
        {
            $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
            $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
            return $newWidth;
        }

        private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
        {
            $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
            $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
            return $newHeight;
        }

        private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            if ($this->height < $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            }
            elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
            // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
            {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
            else
            // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
            {
                if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                } else {
                    // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
            }

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
        {

            $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
            $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

            if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
            } else {
                $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
            }

            $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
            $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

            return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
        {
            // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
            $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
            $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

            $crop = $this->imageResized;
            //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

            // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
            $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
            imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }

        ## --------------------------------------------------------

        public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
        {
            // *** Get extension
            $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
            $extension = strtolower($extension);

            switch($extension)
            {
                case '.jpg':
                case '.jpeg':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                        imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.gif':
                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                        imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                    }
                    break;

                case '.png':
                    // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                    $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                    // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                    $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                    if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                         imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                    }
                    break;

                // ... etc

                default:
                    // *** No extension - No save.
                    break;
            }

            imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
        }
```

?>

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused by your functions file. Are those class methods outside of an actual class? That won't work.

Comment: Hi kontrollfreak,

Well I kept them in same file as of class file But then I am getting  common warning for every functions I am using in class.php

warning is : **functionname() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

Comment: Use include_once("class.php") before foreach, will it fix your issue?

Comment: My guess is, PHP can't access your images. Please remove the @ symbols in front of the imagecreate* fuctions to get a more detailed message.

Comment: Hi Kontrollfreak, it is the thing i guess cause when i removed @, I got warning of "failed to open stream: No such file or directory"..can you please guide me about this. because my link to image folder is correct and images are there only. Please help me off mate.

Answer (score 1):

Please activate the php configuration value "display_errors" to true and then you will see that you try to include the resize class each time you loop through.

Include your class and the top of your script and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put all your functions inside your class file

```
    Class resize
        {

        private $image;
        private $width;
        private $height;
        private $imageResized;

        function __construct($fileName)
        {
            // *** Open up the file
            $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

            // *** Get width and height
            $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
            $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
        }

        // All other functions here ...

       }
```

Comment: Well I did.But then I am getting warning for every functions I am using in class.php

Comment: I don't like that part `$single=explode(',',$tmp);
foreach($single as $single)` can you change it to `$arrSingle=explode(',',$tmp); foreach($arrSingle as $single)` and if this doesn't help please `print_r(explode(',',$tmp))`.

Comment: Hi electroid I changed to what you suggested but It din't help either. Also I printed that array out and it had both the values of tmp array.

I am getting same warning for all the functions
**_functionname()_ expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you get some basic understanding of OOP in PHP: [PHP: Classes and Objects - Manual](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.php)

Second, I hate to do all the work, but here it is:

```
<?php

Class resize
{
    private $image;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $imageResized;

    function __construct($fileName)
    {
        // *** Open up the file
        $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

        // *** Get width and height
        $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
        $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function openImage($file)
    {
        // *** Get extension
        $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

        switch($extension)
        {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.jpeg':
                $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case '.gif':
                $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            case '.png':
                $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                break;
            default:
                $img = false;
                break;
        }
        return $img;
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
    {
        // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
        $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

        $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


        // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


        // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
        if ($option == 'crop') {
            $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
        }
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
    {

       switch ($option)
        {
            case 'exact':
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                break;
            case 'portrait':
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                break;
            case 'landscape':
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                break;
            case 'auto':
                $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                break;
            case 'crop':
                $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                break;
        }
        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
    {
        $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
        $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
        return $newWidth;
    }

    private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
    {
        $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
        $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
        return $newHeight;
    }

    private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        if ($this->height < $this->width)
        // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
        {
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
        }
        elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
        // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
        {
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
        }
        else
        // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
        {
            if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            } else {
                // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
            }
        }

        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
    {

        $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
        $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

        if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
            $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
        } else {
            $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
        }

        $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
        $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

        return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
    {
        // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
        $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
        $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

        $crop = $this->imageResized;
        //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

        // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
        $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }

    ## --------------------------------------------------------

    public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
    {
        // *** Get extension
        $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
        $extension = strtolower($extension);

        switch($extension)
        {
            case '.jpg':
            case '.jpeg':
                if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                    imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                }
                break;

            case '.gif':
                if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                    imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                }
                break;

            case '.png':
                // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                     imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                }
                break;

            // ... etc

            default:
                // *** No extension - No save.
                break;
        }

        imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
    }
}
```

Replace your class.php with this, remove functions.php and make sure your images are accessible, as your code won't throw any errors if those files can't be accessed.

It's a quick and dirty fix. Don't rely on it.

Comment: Hi kontrollfreak, Well I kept class n functions in same file as of class file But then I am getting common warning for every functions I am using in class.php warning is : imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..not only imagesx() but every other image related functions give same warning. Moreover, its working with single image perfectly fine. So images are accessible. guide me about this warnings please. Its freaking me out.